# Onenote API, strange behavior when PATCH from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onenote

I have a Kendo Editor in my web, and a button to save the content to OneNote.

The save button calls this function:

```
updatePageContent: function (pageId, elementId, content) {
        deferred = $q.defer();

        var Request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        Request.open('PATCH', 'https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/pages/' + pageId + '/content');

        Request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        Request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + onenoteApi.token);

        Request.onreadystatechange = onPageUpdated;

        var body = [{
              'target': elementId,
              'action': 'replace',
              'content': '<div data-id=content>' +
                                content +
                         '</div>'
        }]

        Request.send(JSON.stringify(body));

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

And Works fine the first two times, but when I try one third time, something strange happens.

Example:

I have a default paragraph with a text and I add another one:

> Default text
>
> bla1

Save and well. So I add another paragraph:

> Default text
>
> bla1
>
> bla2

Save and well. Another one:

> Default text
>
> bla1
>
> bla2
>
> bla3

Save, and this is the result in onenote:

> bla1
>
> Default text
>
> bla1
>
> bla2
>
> bla3

And blocks de page, if I try to PATCH again, I have an access denied error.

Comment: Well, maybe that's not the issue, but I guess you still need to add quotes in this line `<div data-id="content">`, cause currently this is an invalid Html.

Comment: If I put the quotes, it duplicates them. At the beginning I used them.

Comment: Hi Panzer, engineer from the OneNote API team here. This appears to be a bug on our side. We are investigating and will respond here when it's resolved. Thanks for finding this!

Comment: This behaviour was due to a bug in the OneNote API. It should be resolved shortly; thanks for pointing it out to us. We'd love to send you some OneNote swag in return. Please reach out to me privately if you're interested and we'll get it to you pronto!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an error in the OneNote API and has been fixed server-side. Thanks for reporting!